# WiFi on Acer Aspire with Ubuntu 14.04 randomly disconnects

Tags: networking, wireless, acer

Being new user of Linux, Ubuntu 14.04, and running into some problems, I need your help. I apologize if this question was already asked and answered, I have been trying to find the answer on my own, tried some of the suggested solutions but I still have the same problem.

My laptop WiFi connection randomly disconnects, at any time of the day, and the only solution to connect again is to have laptop restarted. When laptop is used after stand-by time/sleep WiFi is always off/disconnected, and I need to restart the laptop every time in order to have it connected to WiFi again (router is very close to the laptop and all other devices connect to it without any problems).

Would you mind telling me if you need me to post anything here related to the laptop performance/info, and if you can let me know of the possible solution to this problem.

Laptop specs: Acer Apire E5-771G-59HV (if needed)

Thank you in advance, it is quite annoying to have laptop restarted so many times while in the middle of work.

---

As suggested by the fellow user, here's more info:

bozena@Aspire-E5-771G:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280 
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: Personally, I just do `sudo service network-manager restart`, it restarts network manager, and reconnects me automatically without need to reboot

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try a driver parameter; from the terminal:

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Reboot and tell us if stability is improved.

Next, write a configuration file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

Add a single line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Reboot.

We wonder if there is some other module besides rtl8723be that drops and doesn't reload as expected. After a reboot, when wireless is working, run:

```
lsmod  >  wifi.txt
```

Suspend, then resume and when wireless is not working, run:

```
echo ----------------  >>  wifi.txt
lsmod  >>  wifi.txt
rfkill list all  >>  wifi.txt
```

Find the file wifi.txt in your user directory and post it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your reply.

Comment: No change, I tried driver parameter as you wrote, rebooted, have put laptop to sleep and when I started using it again WiFi was disconnected. I had to restart laptop in order to connect to WiFi again.

Comment: But it now only disconnects under suspend, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, at the moment it only disconnects under suspend, that is all I can check at the moment. I would have to wait and see if it continues to disconnect randomly while in use.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Done, rebooted, when under suspend WiFi disconnects, had to restart again in order to connect to WiFi.

Comment: Is it perhaps Network Manager that drops out? Suspend and then do: sudo service network-manager restart. Does the wireless then come back?

Comment: No, wireless does not come back, here's the terminal response: bozena@Aspire-E5-771G:~$ sudo service network-manager restart
[sudo] password for bozena: 
network-manager stop/waiting
network-manager start/running, process 3117

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: May I ask you for the assistance? I am not that proficient user :) How do I find wifi.txt in the user directory?

Comment: Open the file manager, Nautilus, perhaps. By default it opens in your user directory; /home/bozena, for example. It should be there. http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6d4BRxyzS7w/UH1eLnS73EI/AAAAAAAAK3w/6DLrYib15YU/s1600/nautilus-3.6.png

Comment: Hope it's all ok, here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10396871/

Comment: I saw this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1414972 Is wpa_supplicant running after suspend? ps aux | grep -i wpa

Comment: wpa_supplicant after suspend (WiFi disconnected):

bozena@Aspire-E5-771G:~$ ps aux | grep -i wpa 
root       819  0.0  0.0  30608  2728 ?        Ss   20:27   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.pid -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant 
bozena    3076  0.0  0.0  17164   960 pts/0    S+   20:34   0:00 grep --color=auto -i wpa

Comment: wpa_supplicant after restart (WiFi connected):
bozena@Aspire-E5-771G:~$ ps aux | grep -i wpa
root       784  0.0  0.0  30608  2616 ?        Ss   20:36   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.pid -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
bozena    2479  0.0  0.0  17164   960 pts/17   R+   20:37   0:00 grep --color=auto -i wpa

Comment: And is the result the same after suspend?

Comment: Laptop is no longer disconnecting randomly from WiFi while in use. After suspend it is still offline and I need to restart it.

Comment: I have no other suggestions regarding the suspend issue. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I'll work around suspend issue; the main concern was disconnecting from WiFi while in use which is solved now. Thank you again.

Comment: how about trying to suspend and then restarting the network manager ? Try doing this `sudo -s sh -c pm-suspend && service network-manager restart` or more simply `sudo pm-suspend && sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: OK, saw that you already did try that in the comments. Would be nice if you added what you've tried  to the original question. Now, how about removing the rtl8723be module and putting it back again ? Try `sudo rmmod -v rtl8723be; sleep 2; modprobe -v rtl8723be`. You might wanna try to also bring down the card first with `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`. In my experience , I had rtl8192 card, and removing and reinserting r8192e_pci module worked for it